# Como eliminar nomes repetidos com valores carregados?

Tags: php, json

Tenho os seguintes nomes que vem do JSON nessa sequencia

```
[
   {
      "Animal":"Leão"
   },
   {
      "Animal":"Leopardo"
   },
   {
      "Especie":"Aves"
   },
   {
      "Especie":"Mamiferos"
   },
   {
      "Especie":"Répteis"
   },
   {
      "Animal":"Cachorro"
   },
   {
      "Animal":"Gato"
   },
   {
      "Especie":"Peixes"
   }
]
```

Percebam que os nomes que ficam atrás do ':' se repetem e ficam aleatoriamente desorganizados, queria que ficasse nesse modelo:

> **Animal**:
>
> Leão
>
> Leopardo
>
> Cachorro
>
> Gato
>
> **Especie**:
>
> Aves
>
> Mamiferos
>
> Repteis
>
> Peixes

Preciso que a saida seja via: `echo` de forma organizada, como no segundo caso.

Como posso fazer isso? Será que preciso usar Dicionarios e ir incrementando os valores nas chaves?

Comment: Olá Sérgio, seja bem vindo ao SOpt! Insira o JSON que é recebido. A sequencia que você colocou não é um JSON. Isso ajudará alguém a responder sua pergunta de uma forma mais exata.

Comment: Ah sim, melhorei agora

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depende um pouco de como você recebe esse json pelo php. Admitindo este json:

```
[
 {"Animal":  "Leão"},{"Animal":  "Leopardo"},
 {"Especie": "Aves"},{"Especie": "Mamiferos"},
 {"Especie": "Répteis"},{"Animal":  "Cachorro"},
 {"Animal":  "Gato"},{"Especie": "Peixes"}
]
```

Uma forma de fazer pode ser a seguinte:

```
$array = json_decode($contents,true);
//cria duas variaveis para guardar classificações repetidas
$animals = array();
$species = array();

//varre o array gerado pelo json 
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    //colocando valores em suas respectivas categorias
    if (array_key_exists("Animal", $value)){ 
         array_push($animals ,$value["Animal"]); 
    }elseif(array_key_exists("Especie", $value)){
         array_push($species ,$value["Especie"]);
     } 
}

//resultado será um array com chaves das categorias repetidas
//que levam as os valores
$result = array("Animal" => $animals, "Especie" => $species);

//imprimindo
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    echo "{$key}:  \n";
    foreach($value as &$v){
        echo "\t {$v} \n";
    }
 }
```

sairá assim:

```
Animal:
     Leão
     Leopardo
     Cachorro
     Gato
Especie:
     Aves
     Mamiferos
     Répteis
     Peixes
```